# Swing form database connection

Tags: java, database, swing, database-connection

I am new to Java and [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), and I am attempting to create a form that

1. connects to a database using [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) connection
2. reads information from seven columns and displays them on a jTable component already on the form

I already have this working. I am now trying to optimize my code and use a better architecture to separate the database connection and the user interface (UI forms) code so that I can have a separate class to perform the connection and then simply call the method from this class in the code behind the button. The problem with using NetBeans and forms is that I don't know where to instantiate this class and such. Below is a cope of the class that I have created to perform the JDBC connection

```
public class ConnectionManager {
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prototypeeop";
private static String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String username = "root";
private static String password = "triala";
private static Connection con;
private static String url;

public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // log an exception. fro example:
            System.out.println("Failed to create the database connection.");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        // log an exception. for example:
        System.out.println("Driver not found.");
    }
    return con;
}
```

}

This is already a `.java` file. I have a JForm, and I need to call this method behind the button. Here is how I do it in the form currently without using a connection class:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0);
    String sql="Select * from eopdata";
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prototypeeop","root","jakamuga");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String Year=rs.getString("Year");
            String Month=rs.getString("Month");
            String Day=rs.getString("Day");
            String MJD=rs.getString("MJD");
            Double xarcsec=rs.getDouble("xarcsec");
            Double yarcsec=rs.getDouble("yarcsec");
            Double UT1UTCsec=rs.getDouble("UT1UTCsec");
            model.addRow(new Object[] { Year, Month, Day, MJD,xarcsec,yarcsec,UT1UTCsec});
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
```

How can I use the class instead of hard coding in the connection? I have already created the class but where do I instantiate it. Do I do it in the main of the form or do I do it in the actionevent code with the following code?

```
private Connection con = null;
private Statement stmt = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;

con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
stmt = con.createStatement();
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To literally answer your question: your `getConnection` method is a `public static` method so you can call this from anywhere. Just call `ConnectionManager.getConnection()` where-ever you need that connection.

Some other remarks about your code:

- You shouldn't query a database in the `actionPerformed` method. This method is called on the EDT, and doing a database query and looping over the results is a long-running task. Doing this task on the EDT will block your UI. Consult the [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial for more info about Swing and threading
- Consider caching the `Connection` object
- Do not forget to close your resources. If I remember correctly, a `ResultSet` must be closed afterwards. Do this in a finally block

Comment: i shall attempt to just call this method. A follow up to your suggestion so are you saying that i should create a separate class for perfroming the sql query too? i am going to read up on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) but if you could explain more. I think you are saying that i should create a stored procedure and call that instead

Comment: @user1332681 I say you should perform the querying of your database and the parsing of those results in a different thread, and not just a different method. Otherwise you end up with a unresponsive UI

Comment: unfortunately i am a novice and i do not know how to do multi threaded programming

Comment: For example, although a `SwingWorker` is probably better in this case. But this is all explained in that tutorial I linked to in my answer

Comment: appreciate the help and the resources i will first work on getting my db connection object to work and then try to do some multi threading

Comment: also do youhave any advice on how to cache the Connection object and how to close my resources.  A finally block should be efficient for this but what logic should i use?

Comment: sorry i have one last question. I have tried to call Connection.getConnection() in my action event but it doesn't recognize it. In java how do you include (import) all the resources. I added the library class to the project and i can see it in the explorer but how do i include it in my form project. I come from a c++ background

Comment: The right syntax is `ConnectionManager.getConnection()`, my bad. Any decent IDE will suggest to import that class

Comment: robin it worked i now have a connection class that returns a connection..now i need to abstract the sql string and the processing of the result set